# How to compare data in two arrays and return the unmatched array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here is my problem statement.

I have two arrays

```
assignedArr = [{ id: 'abc1' }, { id: 'abc2' }, { id: 'abc3' }];

 unAssignedArr = [{ id: 'abc1' }, { id: 'abc2' }, { id: 'abc3'}, { id: 'abc4' }];
```

I have to compare assingedArr with unAssignedArr, and return the unmatched array item.

For example,  In the above example,

the result should be

```
   newArr = [{ id: 'abc4' }];
```

Like soo...

Any suggestions would greatly appriaciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use array `Array.prototype.filter` with `Array.prototype.some` method to get your result.

```js
const assignedArr = [{ id: 'abc1' }, { id: 'abc2' }, { id: 'abc3' }];

const unAssignedArr = [
  { id: 'abc1' },
  { id: 'abc2' },
  { id: 'abc3' },
  { id: 'abc4' },
];

const ret = [
  ...unAssignedArr.filter((x) => !assignedArr.some((y) => x.id === y.id)),
  ...assignedArr.filter((x) => !unAssignedArr.some((y) => x.id === y.id)),
];
console.log(ret);
```